# Connect to the internet from within a docker container with docker compose on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a fairly simple docker-compose file, as follows:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  synchronisation:
    build: .
    command: 'python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    networks: 
      - syncnet
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8008:8008"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/lib/django
      - packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.5.3
    networks: 
      - syncnet
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: none

volumes:
  packages:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: <somefolder>
      o: bind

networks:
  syncnet:
    name: sync_network
```

Now from the `synchronisation` app I need to perform some requests to the app `neo4j` and to the 'outside world'. Connection to `neo4j` is successful, however the connections to the outside world seem to fail. In particular if I get into the `synchronisation` container and run

```
ping google.com
```

I get the result

```
PING google.com (172.217.17.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6149ms
```

I have already set

`sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`

How can I get access to the 'outside world' to work? It's good to know that I am working from a Mac 10.15.7.